# MySQL missing values from column

Tags: mysql

```
 Radio_ID | Log_ID
 ----------------- 
 1        | 1 
 1        | 2 
 1        | 4 
 1        | 7 
 1        | 10
 2        | 1
 2        | 2
 2        | 3
 2        | 5
```

Is it possible to get the following output in a single sql statement?

Output:

```
Radio_ID | Log_ID
-----------------
 1       | 3
 1       | 5
 1       | 6
 1       | 8
 1       | 9
 2       | 4
```

Logic: returns missing values for each id < max value for id (ex 10 is max value for radio id 1 and missing values are 3,5,6,8,9).
I have a data parser for a radio device and when the radio is outside the coverage area it doesn't send data, so I have to send a new request for missing `Log_ID`s.

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain how from data you need to receive result. I don't get it.

Comment: What determines whether a given `Log_ID` is missing? Is there another table?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any extra table. Only based on this one. NOT IN clause did't work.

Comment: why isnt 1 11 thru 1 infinity missing, for instance

Comment: Because 10 is max value for radio id 1.

Comment: ah, truth be told, we knew we'd fish it out of you

Comment: You need to improve your question, @AdrianStanculescu . We can only help if you tell us enough to provide an answer. How do you define what values you want to get from the table? How is the table meant to know what values **should** exist yet do not?

Comment: You need some way of generating the non-existent data - whether that be at the database level through a sproc or utility table of some kind, or (probably better) at the application level (if that's available to you), e.g. with a simple loop in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a table called `numbers` with integers of a sufficient range.

Then you can do:

```
select r.radio_id, n.n as MissingLogId
from (select radio_id, min(log_id) as minli, max(log_id) as maxli
      from table t
      group by radio_id
     ) r join
     numbers n
     on n.n between r.minli and r.maxli left join
     table t
     on t.radio_id = r.radio_id and t.log_id = n.n
where t.radio_id is null;
```

The idea is to generate all the numbers for each radio id (between the minimum and maximum id) using a `join`.  Then existing values are filtered out.

If you don't have a numbers table handy, you need to create one large enough.  This would probably work:

```
create table numbers (n int primary key);

insert into numbers(n)
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
    from table cross join (@rn := 0);
```

Comment: go with this approach. those helper tables can be invaluable

Comment: Thank you. It works. Hope it will be fast with over 100,000 rows.